# Can a lightning strike ionise the material it strikes?

Tags: meteorology, geology, lightning

I know lightning strikes ionise the air, but I'm looking into geology, specifically amethyst, and found that it gets its colour partially from trivalent iron, iron(III), Fe 3+, whatever you want to call it. Normally this happens by radiation during the formation of the amethyst, but I'm curious if a silica crystal with trace amounts of normal iron could be struck by lightning to ionise it and remove the additional electrons, thereby finalising the creation of amethyst, or am I missing some details about lightning and/or amethyst?

Answer (score 2):

There are [Fulgurites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgurite).

> Fulgurites are formed when lightning strikes the ground, fusing and vitrifying mineral grains.